# laravel JSON validation rule

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use the ['json' validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-json) in a form request, but I constantly get an invalid JSON message. I havent found any examples on how to use this rule, so I'm a bit lost here.

**My rules function looks like this:**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'userData'=>'json',
            'securityChanges'=>'json'
        ]
    }
```

**And my JSON looks like this:**

```
{
    "userData":{
        "domicilio":"nowere",
        "empresa":"Burgerking",
        "name":"zorgito",
        "surname": "perez",
        "cuit":"10101010"
    },
    "securityChanges":{
        "email": "flasheadas@lolo.com",
        "password": "777777777777",
        "passwordConfirmation":"777777777777"
    }
}
```

**My headers are properly set:**

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

**It should work, but I get:**

```
 "The user data must be a valid JSON string."
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

EDIT:
as requested n one of the answers, I'm putting the output of a `dd($this->all());` in my form request class

```
    array:2 [
      "userData" => array:5 [
        "domicilio" => "nowere"
        "empresa" => "Burgerking"
        "name" => "zorgito"
        "surname" => "perez"
        "cuit" => "10101010"
      ]
      "securityChanges" => array:3 [
        "email" => "flasheaasddas@lolo.com"
        "password" => "777777777777"
        "passwordConfirmation" => "777777777777"
      ]

   ]
```

The whole HTTP request is:

```
PATCH /api/users/me HTTP/1.1
Host: DOMAIN REMOVED
Authorization: Bearer (TOKEN REMOVED.)
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 73516b63-8556-4c21-9050-7a4fa3a83cb1

{
    "userData":{
        "domicilio":"nowere",
        "empresa":"Burgerking",
        "name":"zorgito",
        "surname": "perez",
        "cuit":"10101010"
    },
    "securityChanges":{
        "email": "flasheaasddas@lolo.com",
        "password": "777777777777",
        "passwordConfirmation":"777777777777"
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used the `json` validation rule yet, but I could imagine that it expects the json to be in string format. For example see this json object with one property which itself is a string containing another json object: `{"property":"{\"inner\":\"property\"}"}`. If you want to validate nested properties, you can simply use the dot-notation in your validation rules: `$rules = ['nested.property' => 'int']` for input `{"nested": {"property": 123}}`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing clear here, please make dd($request->all()) or dd($this->all()) (if you are in request class directly) and make sure you have that fields, and then make sure that fields are valid json strings. You can check it here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I checked the JSON with jsonLint, I will post the whole request here if that helps.

Comment: I posted a dd output as you asked

Comment: Do you see that userData and securityChanges comes up as arrays? They are not valid jsons, they are arrays

Comment: But why are they being converted to arrays automatically by laravel before getting into the form request?
That kind of defeats the point of having a request validator for JSON.

Comment: public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'userData'=>'array',
            'securityChanges'=>'array'
        ]
    }

This will work but not json validation

Comment: That will validate the Laravel interpretation of the Json object. I want to validate if the user has put valid json in the request body.

Comment: Then you should send it like this 

{
 "userData": "{\"domicilio\":\"nowere\",\"empresa\":\"Burgerking\",\"name\":\"zorgito\",\"surname\": \"perez\",\"cuit\":\"10101010\"}",
 "securityChanges": "{\"email\": \"flasheaasddas@lolo.com\",\"password\": \"777777777777\",\"passwordConfirmation\":\"777777777777\"}"
}